# String object cannot be interprested as an integer

Tags: python

```
l = 'ABCDEFGHIJK'

def a(l):
    letters = [letter for letter in l]
    print(letters)
```

Hi, how can I achieve the Output to be ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']? that is, starting at index 2 and finishing at the last index of l?

More complicatedly, how can I get this Output? ['C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']? That is, start at index 2 of l, if 'F' is found jump until 'H' is found.

Many thanks

Comment: Your code is too confusing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: what are your inputs to the function?

Comment: Because `l[i]` is a string and "range" can't handle it.

Comment: what final result for fucntion?

Comment: `l[i]` is not an integer, it's a string. The `range` function takes integer arguments.

Comment: If you get such errors. look at the line number which is displayed, then if you still don't see, where the problem is, just execute the line part by part, then you will see, where the exception occurs.

Comment: Your question was answered. If you have a followup question, mention it in comments or go submit a new question. You just edited your question, removing the part you originally asked about. Now the accepted answer appears to make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get the following error statement:

```
  File "C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Documents\projects\temp.py", line 7, in a
    hi.append(range(i, l[i]))

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

As you can see, the error is in your call to `hi.append(range(i, l[i]))`.

This is happening because you are trying to call the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) function, which only accepts integers as arguments, with an indexed value from your string `l`. Which means you are passing a `str` to this function where an `int` should go.

If your goal is simply to get a list of individual characters from your string (I'm just guessing here based on your code) you can achieve that by using this:

```py
letters = [letter for letter in l]
print(letters)
```

Out:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I achieve the Output to be ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']? that is, starting at index 2 and finishing at the last index of l?

Comment: More complicatedly, how can I get this Output? ['C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']? That is, start at index 2 of l, if 'F' is found jump until 'H' is found.

Comment: If you know which letters you want to skip you could try `[letter for letter in l if letter != 'G']` or (if you have more than one letter you want to skip) `[letter for letter in l if letter not in ['G', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]`